# Security of the native Password Autofill function in iOS 12

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management

I have read Apple documents on the [iOS 12 password autofill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/) function for iPhones. But I could not find much information pertaining to where the passwords are stored and what vulnerabilities might exist. I understand storage would be either the device or the cloud. Apple Keychain includes a setting for cloud storage, and of course, Apple encrypts the passwords. And the docs suggest that if storage is on the device, it may be with the app itself (this is not clear from my reading). The general overarching security assumption is that the user has access control at the device level (both physical and OS). But eventually, the password has to be entered as "plain text" through the autofill function. So it would seem a point of vulnerability.

Are there any experiments or papers/reports on the security strength of Apple's autofill function?

What security vulnerabilities exist for password exploit/theft for the iOS autofill feature?

Comment: Are you looking for the security of *auto-fill* or the security of password storage?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf Section "User Password Management" covers the technical details.

Comment: Other than what @schroeder's provided, here's some more reading material. Password autofill workflow: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow. Customizing autofill rules: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/customizing_password_autofill_rules and an interesting article on why you shouldn't use Apple's Keychain : https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/why-you-still-shouldnt-use-icloud-keychain-store-your-passwords-ios-12-0187009/

Comment: @schroeder the security of autofill. Decrypting the stores password and adding it to a input field on a form

Comment: If you read the docs, you will see how it works (it's made part of the keyboard)

Comment: Also consider the scenario of losing access to your Apple device. If you don't use the iCloud keychain, keep a copy of all important credentials in a secure location. If you are using the iCloud keychain, there's easy way to export the credentials to a human readable format. You'll need some scripting or 3rd party tools.